# Mercurial: hg unshelve throws error of "unknown bundle version 20"

Tags: mercurial

I shelved my changes in my branch and then tried to unshelve them. I get this error:

```
vagrant@mysite:/var/www/mysite/www$ hg unshelve MYSITE-157-contact-info-for-tda-and-td-av-01
abort: /var/www/MYSITE/.hg/shelved/MYSITE-157-contact-info-for-tda-and-td-av-01.hg: unknown bundle version 20
```

I found posts online with this error in regards to bundles, but not in regards to shelving. What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: That may be related to your hg version, which version are you using? (`hg version -v`). Also could you try rerunning the command with the `--traceback` option so we can get a traceback to more easily fix the situation?

Comment: I think it was a version issue (can't prove it at this point, since I already deleted the shelve). I think the issue was that my VM was on one version of mercurial and my local was on another, and I might have shelved on one and unshelved on another.